# Can't create view from Bigquery command line tools

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to create a view using the bq command line tool.
The bq command line tool version is **2.0.18**

I followed the instruction in this  [page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views):

My command looks like this:

```
mk --view="select title from [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] where contributor_id = 3894110" views.my_test_view
```

I received this output:
`int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

What did I do wrong? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest bq version is 2.0.19. Can you run `gcloud components update` and try again?